# How can I cycle through a list of elements one at a time on an event?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I currently have this function that loops through all the divs and logs their indexes all at once. I want it to only log one index every time I press enter. How would I do that?

```
if (event.key === 'Enter') {
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

    for (var y=0; y<element.length; y++) {
        console.log(y);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: This seems like a possible [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/399876) because it's rather unusual to want to simply log `div` indices. What are you trying to accomplish (application feature) through this?

Comment: Are you just asking how to make this run every time you press Enter? Put it in a `keydown` event listener.

Comment: @ggorlen in my actual code I have a custom html tag but when I asked another question and left this tag as "mark" everyone got so confused and focused on trying to understand what it does so I decided to change it on div this time. The tag name doesnt matter in here

Comment: It's not clear what application feature this implements regardless of the tag. When you have `n` elements and you echo `console.log(i)` for each element, this seems pointless in and of itself. You're just taking a count of the elements and doing nothing with it -- see the xy problem link. What _application feature_ does this implement that a user or programmer ultimately cares about?

Comment: @Barmar I already have this oiece of code in a large event listener function. The problem is with the loop itself. It outputs the indexes all at once. Like: 1 2 3 4 5. I want it to output one index at the time each time I press enter. So like: 1 enter 2 enter 3 enter

Comment: @ggorlen Basically when the user types something in the input it searches through the page for the matched keywords and wrapps them into the custom html tag. Basically I do the search for the page on my website so it works like ctrl+f. And right now I'm trying to figure out how to implement this enter functionality from ctrl+f so it would scroll to the next matched keyword on the page when I click enter. But for this step I just want to figure out how do I loop through all of my keywords, one at the time, when I hit enter

Comment: Gotcha, thanks. If that's the case, don't use a loop -- keep the counter as state outside of the callback, then increment it on enter. I'll add an answer momentarily.

Comment: @Maroun If you don't want it to do them all at once, don't write a loop. Put the current index in a global variable, print just that index, and increment it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comments, it sounds like you want to step through a series of elements in response to the user pressing Enter as part of a search feature. A loop is the wrong tool for the job because it runs to completion instantly, as you found out. Instead, keep index state outside of the callback and increment it by 1 whenever the event fires, optionally using modulus to wrap back to 0. For example,

```js
const markEls = [...document.querySelectorAll("p mark")];
let highlightIndex = markEls.length - 1;

const nextMark = () => {
  markEls[highlightIndex].classList.remove("focused-mark");
  highlightIndex = (1 + highlightIndex) % markEls.length;
  markEls[highlightIndex].classList.add("focused-mark");
};
document.addEventListener("keydown", e => {
  if (e.code === "Enter") {
    nextMark();
  }
});
nextMark();
```

```css
.focused-mark {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

```html
<h4>click in the snippet to give it focus, then press Enter</h4>
<p>
  Quaerat nisi aut id temporibus. Pariatur sit est ut quo sit illum. Omnis et architecto rerum sit et ullam impedit laboriosam. Perspiciatis <mark>numquam aperiam</mark> est et autem porro molestias. Magnam quia explicabo dolores illum. Ea ipsam libero optio nostrum. Temporibus voluptate sunt repudiandae harum eius non. Qui excepturi voluptas qui. Quis ipsa quo <mark>voluptate</mark>. Et non repudiandae quas aut et quae tempore. Qui et ut illum est sint est. Quis veniam molestias eum et. Quia in quia consequatur molestiae. Autem deleniti et et dolores omnis eum. <mark>Pariatur voluptatem</mark> aut aperiam ex delectus et deserunt. Qui omnis eos enim error omnis occaecati dolore. Ut beatae harum doloribus voluptatem. Repellendus qui aut maxime occaecati <mark>quod ad aut</mark>. Possimus optio voluptatibus natus natus.
</p>
```

Comment: I already have the highlighting functionality, that's not what I need. I'm trying to just select the "mark" tags and output their indexes on each enter press

Comment: Does my code not do this? Add a `console.log(highlightIndex)` into `nextMark` and you should be good to go. Do whatever you want in `nextMark` -- it's just a proof of concept pattern which you can modify to suit your needs. The key point is that you use an index rather than a loop to achieve this single-step behavior.